# Angular: The contents are not displayed properly, though no errors are reported

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

***My problem:***

The contents of my app are not displayed properly, and yet no errors are reported. I use Debugger for Chrome, VSCode, as my debugger.

***The Hierarchy Tree:***

`Appcomponent` -> `dishdetailcomponent`

My `dishdetail.component.ts` file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

const DISH = {
  id: '0',
  name: 'Uthappizza',
  image: '/assets/images/uthappizza.png',
  category: 'mains',
  featured: true,
  label: 'Hot',
  price: '4.99',
  // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
  description: 'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
  comments: [
       {
           rating: 5,
           comment: 'Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!',
           author: 'John Lemon',
           date: '2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z'
       },
       {
           rating: 4,
           comment: 'Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!',
           author: 'Paul McVites',
           date: '2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z'
       },
       {
           rating: 3,
           comment: 'Eat it, just eat it!',
           author: 'Michael Jaikishan',
           date: '2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z'
       },
       {
           rating: 4,
           comment: 'Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!',
           author: 'Ringo Starry',
           date: '2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z'
       },
       {
           rating: 2,
           comment: 'It\'s your birthday, we\'re gonna party!',
           author: '25 Cent',
           date: '2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z'
       }
   ]
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dishdetail',
  templateUrl: './dishdetail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dishdetail.component.scss']
})
export class DishdetailComponent implements OnInit {

  dish = DISH

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

My `dishdetail.component.html` file:

```
...
    <div fxFlex *ngIf="dish">
        <h3>
          <b>Comments</b>
        </h3>
        <mat-list *ngIf="comments">
            <mat-list-item *ngFor="let comment of comments">
              <p matline>
              <span>{{comments.comment}} + "\n"</span>
              <span>{{comments.star}} + " Stars" + "\n"</span>
              <span>"-- " + {{comments.author}} + " " + {{comments.date | date}}</span>
              </p>
          </mat-list-item>
        </mat-list>
    </div>
...
```

The word "comments" is displayed properly. Starting with the mat-list tag, everything just disappears. I have read the document and tried with both `mat-list` and `mat-nav-list` tag, and neither of them works for me.

I am quite new to Angular. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: @John "comments" is defined as a part of "dish".

Comment: Exactly! So you need to access `dish.comments` to reach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `*ngIf="dish.comments"`, because `dish` is the only available property inside your component. And also use `comment.comment`, `comment.star` and so on inside the `*ngFor`

```
<div fxFlex *ngIf="dish">
        <h3>
          <b>Comments</b>
        </h3>
        <mat-list *ngIf="dish.comments">
            <mat-list-item *ngFor="let comment of dish.comments">
              <p matline>
              <span>{{comment.comment}} + "\n"</span>
              <span>{{comment.star}} + " Stars" + "\n"</span>
              <span>"-- " + {{comment.author}} + " " + {{comment.date | date}}</span>
              </p>
          </mat-list-item>
        </mat-list>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take **`dish.comments`** here -

```
<mat-list *ngIf="dish.comments">
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let comment of dish.comments">
```

Answer (score 0):

You've placed `dish = DISH` in the class, but you're using `*ngIf="comments"` in the template. You need to access it like `dish.comments`, since that's where it sits on the class.

Not just there, but in a bunch of places where you assume that `comments` exists on the component instance. Alternatively, you can do something like `comment = dish.comments` in the class, and then you don't have to change the template. It's up to you.